# Connect a list to a doc library on a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, library

I have a Sharepoint List (Issue Tracker) on the Hub site A. I also have a document library (Project Docs) on a sub-site of site A. I would like to add a lookup column on the Issue Tracker from the hub site that gets a column from the Project Docs on the sub-site.

I saw where this can be done in reverse using site columns. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible to create a lookup column to get information from subsite using out of box feature in SharePoint Online.